# Need a formula to make Google Sheets choose between two formulas

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm working with Google Sheets. I'm trying to get it to choose between two formulas:

```
=COUNT(L2,M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2,R2)
```

and

```
=IF(S2<232,0,7)
```

In this instance, I'm weighing totals on given days individually vs. the total for the week. `L2`-`R2` correspond to positive values above 43 on each of the days of the week. `S2` represents the total numeric value for the week.

If any of `L2`-`R2` has a numeric value above 43, 1 point is added in the first formula, contained in cell `V`, and that total is the point value for the week.

However, if the total numeric value for the week exceeds 232 for the week, as indicated in the second formula, the point value for the week is 7.

I want a formula that decides that if `=IF(S2<232,0,7)` returns true, have that formula show its output. If it returns false, I want `=COUNT(L2,M2,N2,O2,P2,Q2,R2)` to show its output.

As it stands right now, I have each formula in its own cell and have to visually compare, which is tedious, given the sheer number of times I have to compare.

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: ok so the tags i chose seemed appropriate. one for using formulas in spreadsheet software and another  for using google spreadsheets. that pretty well narrows the field a bit. so in dont understand the first comment.as for being on topic, this is regarding the use of a specific piece of software, which falls within the topic guidelines.

Comment: You **still** haven't **read** the tags. "Questions about Google Spreadsheets are off topic and should be asked on webapps.stackexchange.com"

Comment: then i shall do so there.

Comment: i didnt understand because i am very new to this site and thought choosing the google spreadsheets tag would suffice for help in using google spreadsheets